# Why the $\|x\|^2$ does not equal to $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, numerical-linear-algebra

In the following, why the yellow part is not equal to just (Y-X beta)? Since the double bar represents the Euclidean norm, which has a square root of it, then isn't squaring the square root returns (Y-X beta) only? TIA.

[image: Fig1]

Comment: $\|x\|^{2}$ is non-negative number and $x$ is a vector. They cannot be equal

Comment: There is a square root in the definition of norm, yes. Specifically, $\lVert x\rVert=\sqrt{x^\top x}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @geetha290krm, thanks for providing the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $Y-X\beta$ is not a non-negative real number.

Norms can be defined for all sorts of things: real numbers, complex numbers, vectors, matrices, operators... For any kind of $x$, the norm $||x||$ is by definition a non-negative real number. But $x$ itself need not be a non-negative real number at all. If it isn't, as here, it clearly can't be $||x||^{2}$.

Comment: I see sometimes the norms like ||x|| without any superscript or subscript, they refer to Euclidean norm automatically? I always have confusion between ||x||^2, ||x||_2 and their differences.

Comment: No. It is very usual to use $||x||$ also for non-Euclidean norms. Often, writers assume it is clear from the context which norm is being used. This is done to avoid overloading notation with sub- and superscripts.

Comment: aha, would like to confirm that Euclidean norm would forever be like ||x||_2 instead of ||x||^2, where the latter refers to the square of 'whatever norm the context refers to'?

Comment: Using $\Vert x \Vert^2$ would be very confusing notation for the Euclidian norm. You should certainly assume that it refers to the square of whatever norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is. (Often it will be the Euclidean norm because in that case, squaring gets rid of the square root, which is frequently useful.)